# Minimizing the max function

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose we have the single-variable function $$f(x) = \max_k \{f_k(x)\}$$ where each $f_k$ is convex and smooth (and known beforehand). We want to minimize it over some bounded interval. We can, in $\mathcal{O}(k)$ time, evaluate $f$ and also get a list of which $k$:s are active (i.e. we can characterize the full subdifferential at any $x$ easily).

If all the breakpoints are known beforehand, I think we can solve this analytically in $\mathcal{O}(k^2)$ time. But what if they're not? Is a fast analytic solution still possible? Can we perhaps find the breakpoints easily? Especially interested in the case where each $f_k$ is a convex polynomial.

Comment: That's naive, but can't you first study the $\binom{k}{2}$ difference functions  $f_i-f_j$ on the interval, to find the breakpoints (i.e., you will know when $f_j \geq f_i$ for any pair $(i,j)$, and then infer the maximum of all $f_j$ on any interval — this should be $O(k^2)$ time), reducing this to the case where all the breakpoints are known?
(in any case, you will also have a hidden dependence on the number of breakpoints in your time complexity)

Comment: Yeah something like that. I strongly suspect the polynomial case is WAY easier than the general case - solving $f_i = f_j$ could be tough when the functions are arbitrary. Take the case $e^x$ and $-x$ for instance.

Comment: Sure -- for polynomials, the "basic step" is probably much more computation-friendly (yet, this will still require the $\Theta(k^2)$ computations).

Comment: I have a particular beef with the general obsession with so-called "analytic" solutions. For one thing, if you can't find the breakpoints and/or individual minimums analytically, you don't have an analytical solution. Furthermore, some sort of bisection combined with local gradient/Newton, followed by a final scrubbing step when a single function is isolated, will give you *exactly the same answer* as you're going to come up with here---and, I'll bet, faster than what you'll come up with, too.

Comment: Michael: does the beef still hold if I need to resolve the problem over and over with a lagrange multipler times x tacked on? I only need to find the breakpoints ONCE to know the breakpoints of every single Lagrangian subproblem. I.e. if we're not counting the set-up work for finding the breakpoints, would bisection/Newton still be better?

Comment: @MichaelGrant Would be very interested in hearing your thoughts actually!

Comment: I can certainly see a benefit to precomputing or caching the breakpoints in this case, sure.